# Problem with JscrollPane containing iframes

Tags: jquery, iframe, jscrollpane, facebook-like, jquery-jscrollpane

I am creating a page with a scrollable content area that has to have a facebook like button inside it and customized scrolling bars.  This was not a problem jscrollpane and the facebook iframe set up for the like button.  I tested it on all the browsers i had and sent it to the client for approval

my client is using firefox 3.5.7 and i use 3.6.10 and my client has noticed an error.  basically while he is scrolling, wherever the iframe of the facebook like button should be behind the text (since overflow is hidden for the scroll) the content starts moving around. It kind of looks like while the scrolling is going on the content where the iframe is stays in place for a second, like it is lagging.

i already checked to make sure a simple CSS scroll area would work fine and it does.

here is a link to some simple code that recreates the issue (thanks to vitch):
http://jsfiddle.net/wpaflight/zRQ8z/

has anyone else had this issue before?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't heard of anything like that before. You could try setting the position of the iframe to relative to bring it out of the flow of the document to see if that would help.

Otherwise, can you provide an example URL (if your project is private then a simplified URL showing the problem would be great)?

Comment: its set up locally and we only allow certain servers to see it but i think i explained the issue well:  the pane that is scrolling contains an iframe (in this case the facebook like button) and as you scroll around where the like button would be (if visible) is making the content move around.  this only happens while scrolling and the facebook like button is not visible

Comment: actually... when it is visible it does the same thing... only you see the content of the like button displaying weird instead of whatever is currently covering it

Comment: I understand your description of the problem but without seeing it I can't debug and unfortunately I don't have the time to set up an example page in an attempt to reproduce it. If you can set up a page showing the issue in http://www.jsfiddle.net/ then I'll be glad to try to help further.

Comment: never knew a site like that existed, thank you, i updated the main post with a link to it

Comment: Thanks for the testcase :) This makes it much easier to track down! And glad you like jsfiddle - it certainly is a great way to demo issues like this... On my computer (OS X with Firefox 3.6.12) your demo works correctly (e.g. no wiggling). I will try on some other computers to see if I can replicate...

Comment: Hmmm - trying on Windows XP with Firefox 3.6.12 and it appears to work fine there too! Do you see the problem in the latest Firefox?

Comment: no i dont, but that is the issue, i actually have to work on this problem on another computer in the office that is not up to date.  we told the client that it was an issue but we have no solution yet other than updating the browser.  i know its a pain to do something like this because as developers im sure we all update our browsers all the time but everyone else doesnt.

Comment: I'm afraid it sounds like a bug with Firefox 3.5. I'm surprised your client hasn't updated - Firefox is fairly aggressive these days about recommending updates and downloading them in the background. You could try tweaking the CSS (remove float: left from connect_widget_like_button) or removing the table and using just CSS to lay out the like buttons. Since I can't replicate I'm afraid I can't help any further...